# Starting a Timer Intermittently Deadlocks at Application Startup

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, timer

I have an application with two separate GUI threads, and the main Form is run on each thread. (This is to allow simultaneous independent users on different screens.)

Each of these windows has an InactivityTimer component, which is used to take the user back to the homepage after they have been inactive for a certain period of time.

The pertinent parts of the main function:

```
static void Main()
    {
        MainWindow form1 = new MainWindow(true);

        //check that we have a second screen
        if (Screen.AllScreens.Length > 1)
        {   //Setup the second screen on its own thread and bind events between the two
            System.Threading.Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
            {
                MainWindow form2 = new MainWindow(false);
                form2.FormClosed += (o, e) =>
                {
                    form1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                    {
                        form1.Close();//close form1 when form2 closes. we dont need vice-versa because form2 is on a background thread.
                    });
                };

                /* Logic that binds events between the two forms*/

                Application.Run(form2);
            })
            { IsBackground = true };
            thread.Start();
        }
        Application.Run(form1);
    }
```

The InactivityTimer:

```
public partial class InactivityTimer : System.Windows.Forms.Timer, IMessageFilter
{
    public InactivityTimer()
    {
        Initialise();
    }

    public InactivityTimer(IContainer container)
    {
        Initialise();
        container.Add(this);
    }

    private void Initialise()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
    }              

    public void ResetTimer()
    {
        Stop();
        Start();
    }

    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        bool watching = /*logic that determines whether this is a message we are watching for (mainly mouse actions)*/;
        if (watching)
        {
            ResetTimer();
        }
        return false;//do not stop the event being dispatched
    }   
}
```

When I start the application, one of the screens always shows up before the other, which is not unexpected. But sometimes (*not always*) when I interact with that screen before the other has shown up, the application just stops, as though deadlocked. The second screen never shows and the first screen stops responding to input.

If I 'Break All' in debug mode when this happens, the application is always stuck on the `Start();` in the `ResetTimer()` of the InactivityTimer.

I have seen similar behaviour once before with a timer that I believed was because it was sometimes being started before it's parent control's handle was created, and that was 'fixed' by not attempting to start the timer if IsHandleCreated was false.
But:
a)  I don't even know for certain that it wasn't just a change of the timing fixing it;
b)  In this case, I'm fairly certain the parent handle is already created since the window is showing;
c) That same fix hasn't worked here.

I've been digging into this for a while now and getting nowhere. Even worse, I can't seem to replicate the issue in a pared down application. But I just can't imagine anything that would be getting in the way of a timer calling start on itself after stop worked just fine.

If anyone can please figure out **what's going on here and/or figure out a fix for it** that would be amazing.

Comment: Are there any synchronization mechanisms in your application that you aren't showing here, e.g. locks or semaphores?

Comment: I am using `lock(/*lock object*/){}` blocks in various places, but these are all small sections that don't do a lot, and different lock objects are used in completely unrelated sections of the application. In the worst case I might get a small amount of contention, but no deadlocks.

Comment: Those are the only things that would cause a deadlock.  You need to show us all relevant code if we're going to have a chance of helping you figure it out.

Comment: But how could any lock I have possibly make a call to `Start()` (which is directly inherited from the windows libraries) block?

Comment: I'm not sure.  Can you boil this down to an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I'm having difficulty doing so. I think that problem is related to some sort of race condition, so when I strip the application down, the load time decreases to the point where it's nigh impossible to trigger the issue. I'm still trying, but don't expect one anytime soon unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only just today lucked into figuring out what was going on, because the debugger suddenly stopped in a completely different place.

rory.ap was correct in the comments that only things like locks, etc. would cause such a deadlock. However when I was looking over my code, it just never clicked that `Invoke` acts like such a construct (wrt the UI thread), so I wasn't paying attention to these.

However today my attention was drawn to it and low-and-behold I have an `Invoke` inside a `lock`, which is causing a deadlock.